# Search Engine Optimization: How do sites like Yellow Pages get all their listings found by search engines

Tags: asp.net, seo, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to build a locally-based restaurant listing/reviews site.  I can't help but notice that if I search for a restaurant on the web that sites like Yellow Pages or Yelp have a listing that appears at the top of the list for that restaurant.  Obviously they don't have a separate web page for every restaurant in the US, but somehow their database of info is being read by the search engine.  How is that accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with c#?

Comment: I would put this in an answer, but I feel it is going to sound a bit snarky, so I'll content myself with a comment. I would suspect they have properly researched SEO techniques and have asked questions in the appropriate areas. Like, instead of using c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008 and seo tags on StackOverflow, they will have gone to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ and asked questions there.

Comment: @inksmithy I think the question is less about the SEO and more about the method used to make it seem like the site has a page for every database entry.

Comment: @saluce fair enough, but still, I would expect webmasters.stackexchange to be a better resource for that sort of thing than stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate the feedback.  I will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is stored in a database, and a template page just pulls up the information from the database and displays it.  The URL *appears* to be a unique page for the restaurant by clever use of URL re-writing or, in .NET, using [routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Routing basically takes a GET parameter from the url, incorporates it into the URL as a pseudo-path, then uses that parameter to get the database record to display the restaurant.